# Instruments:UI Automation:iPhone app - how to tap "null" button using parameters of NSRect?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, instruments, ios-ui-automation

please help me.
There is a button:

4) UIAButton [name:(null) value:(null) NSRect: {{25, 254}, {70, 72}}]

I can tap it :
target.tap(x,y)  or window.buttons()[index].tap();

But, is it possible to tap button using parameters NSRect as id of button?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

button can be tapped directly by using its name as a parameter but as in this case name is null, you can tap on it by giving id starting from 0 and goes on up-to number of buttons present on screen just like an array. `NSRect` can't be used here.